# UWP Change Grid.HorizontalAlignment to stretch/left using VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager, adaptive-trigger

I'm having trouble getting the visual state manager to correctly change the HorizontalAlignment/VerticleAlignment of the main grid of my application.

For screen sizes that would be used on phone, I want the HorizontalAlignment/ VerticleAlignment to stretch, with Height/Width set to Auto.

For Desktop it should be Left/Top with Height/Width set to a specific size. For whatever reason when I try to mess with the alignment it acts quirky and does not do what I want

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="PhoneView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.VerticleAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.Width" Value="Auto"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="DesktopSmall">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1920"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.VerticleAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.Height" Value="1280"/>
                    <Setter Target="Grid.Width" Value="1920"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Another issue is when I try to set the max resolution to 1920x1280, if I manually set the height/width of the Grid, the Windows TaskBar (the OS taskbar, not the applications app bar/command bar) cuts off part of my application. I don't want to set the alignments to stretch, because I'm trying to limit the real time stretching of the view.

Thanks! Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Is `Grid` is your name of your `Grid`? If yes then change it to a different name. If no then Use `Grid` name instead of `Grid`.

Comment: Grid is not the name of my grid. I've been using "Container", so Container.HorizontalAlignment for example.

Comment: I used grid as a placeholder in this example only, so it would be clear that it was a grid I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should write like this -

```
<Setter Target="Container.(Grid.HorizontalAlignment)" Value="Left" />
<Setter Target="Container.(Grid.VerticalAlignment)" Value="Top" />
```

---

I have some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475251/setter-target-give-me-an-error-with-relativepanel-alignhorizontalcenterwithpane/44480462#44480462) for creating visual state setters without writing a single line of code.

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I remember now that the nesting is sometimes really strange. Would you have any idea why visual states are not working when the visualstatemanager is placed inside of a Pivot DataTemplate? I've done it with listviews with no problem, but it's acting funky in the pivot.

Comment: You will need to wrap what's in your data template in a `UserControl`. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088500/adaptivetrigger-and-datatemplate).

Comment: Ok, so I tried as you suggested and originally it threw an exception. I tried your second method and it seems to be working. The code that it auto writes is:  `<Setter Target="Container.FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Value="Left"/>`

Comment: I'll also try the UserControl, thanks for the advice!

Comment: That's because the type of your control is not a `Grid` as you mentioned in your question. :) And Yes, `FrameworkElement` will work too. If you think this helps you, consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: I think there may have been miscommunication on my part, apologies. The control "Container" is a Grid, but either way you lead me to the answer so I am grateful. Can I use the method you described to also modify the width of ColumnDefinitions? I can't seem to find that option using the States/Object&Timeline tabs

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Because if it's a Grid then it should just work as Grid inherits from FE.   I also use this piece of code in my project. Regarding column definitions I believe it can be code generated too but I will need to test it out. Will let you know.

Comment: Hmm... Looks like you can change the column/row definitions on the Properties of the Blend Designer, but the value is not recorded in the timeline. So you will have to manually write it unfortunately.

Comment: Came across something strange. I tried to use the automatic method to modify the Horizontal/Verticle alignments just as I did in a test project. For whatever reason, when I go into the Grid's properties, it's not adding the Setter, but instead modifying the actual initial properties. When I tried to do it manually as I did before (which had worked), I get an exception stating that it can't find the property.

Comment: I suspect this is a VS/ Blend bug. Maybe try restarting your VS/Blend.

Comment: Agreed, most likely a bug. If I find a definite fix to it, I will be sure to update this thread. Thank you again for your help.