# Can I change the Canvas.Zindex of an object using visual states?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstates

How could I change the Canvas.Zindex of an object using visual states? I was expecting to be able to do something like this..

```
            <VisualState x:Name="MyVisualState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyObject.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="MyObject.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Target="MyObject.Canvas.ZIndex" Value="12" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
```

But this does not work. I have not been able to find any examples on how to do this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go. Note you need the `()` there because `Canvas.ZIndex` is an attached property and that's how you define the value of it in XAML.

```
<VisualState x:Name="MyVisualState">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="MyObject.Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="MyObject.Background"
                Value="Transparent" />

        <Setter Target="MyObject.(Canvas.ZIndex)"
                Value="12" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

You might be interested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480462/231837) which will show you how to generate the code above without writing a single line of code.